# uwsgi not treating threads fairly

Tags: python, multithreading, nginx, queue, uwsgi

I'm running uwsgi 2.0 with threads enabled on top of nginx. Here is some of the relevant settings:

```
processes = 8
enable-threads = true
threads = 4
master
lazy-apps
single-interpreter
socket-timeout = 30
listen = 1000
```

In python I have a thread inside my app to consume from a queue but since I migrated from apache to nginx/uwsgi it looks like it is taking longer for the consumer thread to process. It appears as if uwsgi is not giving the same priority to the consumer thread that it gives to the main thread:

```
def produce(self):
  while True:
    try:
      item = self.queue.get_nowait()
      self.producer(*item)
  except Empty:
    log.debug('Nothing to produce sleep .1 sec and continue')
    time.sleep(0.1)
  except Exception as e:
    log.error('Producer error: {0}'.format(e))
```

I tried different settings for the sleep and also a blocking get (self.queue.get()) but the fact is that previously I did not have that issue with apache/mod_wsgi, the put/get was pretty much in sync.

Here is the code that initializes the queue:

```
def __init__(self, config, producer_type='producer'):
  # import the producer module, factory and create instance with fabric param
  self.producer = import_producer(producer_type,  config)
  self.queue = Queue()
  self.process_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.produce)
  self.process_thread.daemon = True
  self.process_thread.start()
```

Wondering what I can be doing wrong here? Performance works great is just this queueing that is a problem.

Comment: One thing that I was wondering is whether using the uwsgi queuing framework would be a better solution. Having a shared queue would prevent requests from been dropped when individual worker threads restart, however not sure if that addresses the starvation issue

Comment: can you add some more detail ? For example how much time the thread requires to consume the queue on uWSGI and on mod_wsgi? Does this consumer constantly run independently by request cycle ? Are you sure multiprocessing is not faking you ? Can you describe why you need such a queue (most of the time this kind of approaches are flaky-by-design)

Comment: regarding uWSGI queue framework, each queue is shared by all processes, so it would work very differently from a thread queue where each process has its independent queue

Comment: The consumer could be slower I guess but the puts/gets are pretty in sync if I use apache/mod_uwsgi (I have metrics monitoring #puts/#gets/size of the queue). Did not understand the comment about "multiprocessing faking". The main thread is a REST API where clients connect to send data to a backend application so I don't want the clients to block the connection waiting for the backend processing to happen.

Comment: Regarding the uwsgi queue framework, I'm actually fine with it working differently, my question is more if it is appropriated for such a use case.